# The storage engine MEMORY doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I'm in the process of changing a small web application I work on from using LIKE to MATCH for string queries, but I'm having an issue with a specific query that I need to get working (not the full query, but for the sake of brevity I've removed everything extra):

```
SET @n=0;
SET @pubdate='';
SELECT a.idArticle, CONCAT(a.date, '_', LPAD(a.n, 3, '0')) as alt_id, a.source, a.title, a.datetime
FROM (SELECT idArticle,title,datetime,source, @n:=CASE WHEN @pubdate = date(datetime) THEN @n + 1 ELSE 1 END AS n, @pubdate:=date(datetime) as date FROM article ORDER BY date, idArticle) a 
WHERE (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('query') ) 
ORDER BY a.idArticle DESC
```

This query allows me to generate an ID for an article in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD_n", where the date is the article's publication date and n is the Nth article entered into the database with that date (so the 22nd article published on May 20, 2020 would be 2020-05-20_022).

Upon running the query, I get the error:

```
#1214 - The storage engine MEMORY doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

Similar questions asked here tell people to change InnoDB to MyISAM because InnoDB used to not support fulltext searching. I'm running MariaDB 10.3.16 via XAMPP and it must be recent enough to where that doesn't apply, as a query like this works, and according to `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database`, all my tables run on InnoDB:

```
SELECT * from article WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ("query")
```

So, it seems to be the fancy incrementing subquery but I don't know why this causes a problem. What's going wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Since `MEMORY` tables are lost on restart, all indexes on such tables are lost.  `FULLTEXT` is non-trivial to rebuild.  What's wrong with simply creating an InnoDB table instead of a MEMORY table?

Beware of @ variables; they may not act the way you expect, especially when using subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've basically just stored the @ variables as a column for the time being to work around this. According to SHOW TABLE STATUS though, all of my tables are InnoDB.